# Referring to Membership Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, asp.net-membership

I am using code that inherits `SqlMembershipProvider`, named `MyMembershipClass` so that I can make use of the functions.

I have created my inherited class and specified it in the `Web.config` file like so:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipClass">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyMembershipClass" type="MyMembershipClass" applicationName="/"/> 
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Now that I have done that, to make use of the Membership functions, do I refer to it within my code as:

`MyMembershipClass` or just `Membership`?

**EDIT:**

If you refer to it at just `Membership`, is this due to `defaultProvider="MyMembershipClass"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as `Membership`. It will automatically map to your defined membership class. That enables to change the provider later without needing to change all of your code.

So you don't have to write:

```
MyMembershipClass.GetUser
```

but

```
Membership.GetUser
```

By the way, the same is true if you define a custom `RoleProvider`, for example:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, roleName);
```

**Edit**:

> If you refer to it at just Membership, is this due to
>   defaultProvider="MyMembershipClass"?

Yes, that must be the name of your class that inherits from `MembershipProvider` (or another class inheriting from it like `SqlMembershipProvider`).

According to your second comment that you can define what you want even if it doesn't exist, i get an exeption if i name the provider "Bob" in web.config:

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
>       Exception message: Default Membership Provider could not be found.

Comment: Please see edit, I'd appreciate the additional information just for clarification :)

Comment: The reason why I ask, is that if I misspell MyMembershipClass within any piece of that code in the Web.config, it doesn't cause an error at all!  I could enter the `defaultProvider="bob"` and it it still functions.  hmmm...

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm going to accept this as the answer to my question.  I don't suppose you know why when I change the names within the config that it doesn't cause any errors?

Comment: @Coulton: I'm not sure why you don't get an exception unlike me.

Comment: I managed to get it to error.  It's because I was creating an instance of the class name within my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just Membership.  The static methods on Membership will call the methods on your provider.

Comment: Please see edit, I'd appreciate the additional information just for clarification :)